# Slack app.message is reacting toold messages

Tags: python, slack, slack-api

Im trying to create a slack bot with slack_bolt package that is searching if there are matches in slack history in the channel on a new message. For some reason app.message is triggered on messages that have been sent before the app was running. Is this preventable or do i have to handle this case? It would be to best to prevent it since if i want to use this on a channel with a big history that might cause some problems. I don't want it to check all the X thousand messages in the history.

**wanted result:**

ME: Hi!

-- starting slack app --

ME: Hi!

SlackBOT in thread: A similar message has been posted: (link to first massage)

**result:**

ME: Hi!

SlackBOT in thread: A similar message has been posted (link to itself) *(this only arrives after the slackbot message to the second Hi)*

-- starting slack app --

ME: Hi!

SlackBOT in thread: A similar message has been posted (with link to first message)

```
import os
import json
import ssl
import certifi
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_sdk.web import WebClient
from slack_bolt.adapter.socket_mode import SocketModeHandler
from utils import get_list_of_same_message_indexes, get_ts_of_message_for_link

history_limit = 50
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
slack_client = WebClient(token=os.environ['BOT_TOKEN'], ssl=ssl_context)
app = App(client=slack_client)

@app.message(".*")
def check_history(message, say):
    # say() sends a message to the channel where the event was triggered
    history = app.client.conversations_history(channel=slack_channel_ID,limit=history_limit).get("messages")
    #if the message is not comming from a thread
    print(message.get("text"))
    if not message.get("thread_ts"):
        print("new message")
        thread= message.get("ts")
        list_of_same_messages = get_list_of_same_message_indexes(message,history)
        if len(list_of_same_messages) > 0:
            print(list_of_same_messages)
            example_ts = get_ts_of_message_for_link(history[list_of_same_messages[0]])
            print(example_ts)
            #channel = history[list_of_same_messages[0]].get("channel")
            message_text = f"A similar message has been posted: https://test-dev.slack.com/archives/{slack_channel_ID}/p{example_ts}"
            say({"text": message_text,"thread_ts": thread})
    else:
        print("Nothing")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    SocketModeHandler(app, os.environ["APP_TOKEN"]).start()
```

Comment: If you are just wanting to get new messages there is no reason to be calling `conversations.history`. You can just use the Events API and subscribe to the `message` event type. The `conversations.history` method captures all messages in a channel which might be why you are facing the problem you're having.

Comment: I want to compare the new message to the old ones. Thats why I need conversation_history.